# Does it matter which merchant I sell my items to?

Tags: diablo-iii

Does it matter which merchant I sell my items to or do I get the same price across all?

Are there "types" of merchants that I should stick to for better prices?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I went to all available merchants in Act 2 (just in the camps though) and looked if there was a difference: There isn't. The selling price always is the standard price that you can see on items, even if you're not currently in a merchant dialogue.

If you want some real advice, though: The best merchants are players. If you're looking for good items, check the auction house. The items might be expensive, but you will get good items, and sometimes still for relatively low cost, way ahead of the quality that you're going to get from merchants (especially rares).

The same way, if you have any rares or other powerful magic items, rather sell them in the auction house than to merchants, unless you need the crafting materials.

Answer (score 6):

Nope. All items have the same "vendor price" regardless of whom you decide to offload your loot onto.